# How do I simulate a gas behavior in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, simulator

I'm still currently at high-school, and my self-taught programming knowledge isn't that accurate at all.
By the way, I worked on many projects(I code in C, C++, Python, HTML, JavaScript) and the one I'm currently working on has been giving me a hard time: a simulator for a gas sample's behavior(following Maxwell-Boltzmann's law of distribution for speeds).
M-B distribution is a kinda hard and advanced physics argument especially for my high-school standards, but I still managed to understand its functioning and found out the equation that gives the number of molecules with a velocity between v and v+dv:[M-B equationhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4IR6.gif).
Now, programming JS part takes place, and in the following snippet I inserted the 
balls constructor part, the draw() core function and the part where I spawn balls(100, just as a test, since they should be around 1000) according to M-B equation; now, I think everything should be fine, but spawned balls behave very strangely changing direction whenever they want to, and sometimes getting stuck with each other instead of elastically bouncing off... could you please take a look at the "spawning" part and see if somethings wrong? Then, I also uploaded the whole HTML+JS+CSS code so you can try it, and also verify JS functions for ball-to-ball and ball-to-wall collisions and all that kind of stuff.
I would extremely appreciate it if someone could please help me... I'm confused. 
Heartfelt thanks in advance for any answer, 
Greg.

```js
class Ball {
    
    constructor(x, y, dx, dy, radius){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;

        // mass is that of a sphere as opposed to circle
        // it *does* make a difference in how realistic it looks
        this.mass = this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
        this.color = 'red';
    };    

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y), this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };

    speed() {
        // magnitude of velocity vector
        return Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
    };
    angle() {
        // velocity's angle with the x axis
        return Math.atan2(this.dy, this.dx);
    };
    onGround() {
        return (this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height)
    };
};

function draw() {
    
    currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    dt = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000; // delta time in seconds
    
    // dirty and lazy solution
    // instead of scaling down every velocity vector
    // we decrease the speed of time
    dt *= 0.1;

    if (clearCanv) clearCanvas();
    canvasBackground();
    
    if (!paused) {
        moveObjects();
        ballCollision();
    }
    
    drawObjects();
    
    //logger();
    
    lastTime = currentTime;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

let N = 500;
let m = 2.66e-26;
let T = 300;
let dV = 50;
let k = 1.38e-23;
let v = 50;
let balls = 0;
let anglex;

for(let i = 0; i < 29; i++) { //each 50m/s, with dv = 50, until 1500m/s, 
    probArray[i] = Math.floor(4 * Math.PI * N * (((m) / (2 * Math.PI * k * T))**1.5) * (v**2) * Math.exp((-m) / (2 * k * T) * (v**2)) * dV);//molecules num between v e v+50
    v += 50;
}
v = 50;
for(let i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    let n = 0;
    while(n < probArray[i] && balls < 100) {
        anglex = ((Math.random() * 360) * Math.PI) / 180; //converted in radians;
        vel = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) + v); 
        objArray[objArray.length] = new Ball(randomX(), randomY(), Math.cos(anglex) * vel, Math.sin(anglex) * vel, 3);
        n++;
        balls++;
    }
    v += 50;
    }
```

```js
class Ball {
    
    constructor(x, y, dx, dy, radius){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;

        // mass is that of a sphere as opposed to circle
        // it *does* make a difference in how realistic it looks
        this.mass = this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
        this.color = 'red';
    };    

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y), this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };

    speed() {
        // magnitude of velocity vector
        return Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
    };
    angle() {
        // velocity's angle with the x axis
        return Math.atan2(this.dy, this.dx);
    };
    onGround() {
        return (this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height)
    };
};


//FUNCTIONS

//will remove
function randomColor() {
    let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;
    let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;
    let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 127;

    // dim down the small balls
    if (!bigBalls){
        red *= 0.65
        green *= 0.65
        blue *= 0.65
    }

    let rc = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    return rc;
}

function randomX() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    if (x < 30) {
        x = 30;
    } else if (x + 30 > canvas.width) {
        x = canvas.width - 30;
    }
    return x;
}

function randomY() {
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    if (y < 30) {
        y = 30;
    } else if (y + 30 > canvas.height) {
        y = canvas.height - 30;
    }
    return y;
}

//will remove
function randomRadius() {
    if (bigBalls) {
        let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 + 20);
        return r;
    } else {
        let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2 + 2);
        //let r = 5;
        return r;
    }
}

//will remove
function randomDx() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 4);
    return r;
}

//will remove
function randomDy() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 3);
    return r;
}

function distanceNextFrame(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a.x + a.dx - b.x - b.dx)**2 + (a.y + a.dy - b.y - b.dy)**2) - a.radius - b.radius;
}

function distance(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)**2 + (a.y - b.y)**2);
}

let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let objArray = [];
let probArray = [];
let paused = false;
let bumped = false;

let leftHeld = false;
let upHeld = false;
let rightHeld = false;
let downHeld = false;
let arrowControlSpeed = .25;

let gravityOn = false;

let clearCanv = true;

let bigBalls = false;

let lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
let currentTime = 0;
let dt = 0;

let numStartingSmallBalls = 500;
let numStartingBigBalls = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function keyDownHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 80) { // p
        paused = !paused;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 82) { // r
        objArray = [];
    } else if (event.keyCode == 75) { // k
        clearCanv = !clearCanv;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 88) { // x
        bigBalls = !bigBalls;
    }
}



function canvasBackground() {
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(215, 235, 240)";
}

function wallCollision(ball) {
    if (ball.x - ball.radius + ball.dx < 0 ||
        ball.x + ball.radius + ball.dx > canvas.width) {
        ball.dx *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y - ball.radius + ball.dy < 0 ||
        ball.y + ball.radius + ball.dy > canvas.height) {
        ball.dy *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
        ball.y = canvas.height - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.y - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.y = ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width) {
        ball.x = canvas.width - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.x = ball.radius;
    }    
}

function ballCollision() {
    for (let i=0; i<objArray.length-1; i++) {
        for (let j=i+1; j<objArray.length; j++) {
            let ob1 = objArray[i]
            let ob2 = objArray[j]
            let dist = distance(ob1, ob2)

            if (dist < ob1.radius + ob2.radius) {              
                let theta1 = ob1.angle();
                let theta2 = ob2.angle();
                let phi = Math.atan2(ob2.y - ob1.y, ob2.x - ob1.x);
                let m1 = ob1.mass;
                let m2 = ob2.mass;
                let v1 = ob1.speed();
                let v2 = ob2.speed();

                let dx1F = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1-m2) + 2*m2*v2*Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.cos(phi) + v1*Math.sin(theta1-phi) * Math.cos(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dy1F = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1-m2) + 2*m2*v2*Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.sin(phi) + v1*Math.sin(theta1-phi) * Math.sin(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dx2F = (v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi) * (m2-m1) + 2*m1*v1*Math.cos(theta1 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.cos(phi) + v2*Math.sin(theta2-phi) * Math.cos(phi+Math.PI/2);
                let dy2F = (v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi) * (m2-m1) + 2*m1*v1*Math.cos(theta1 - phi)) / (m1+m2) * Math.sin(phi) + v2*Math.sin(theta2-phi) * Math.sin(phi+Math.PI/2);

                ob1.dx = dx1F;                
                ob1.dy = dy1F;                
                ob2.dx = dx2F;                
                ob2.dy = dy2F;
          
                staticCollision(ob1, ob2)
                
            }            
        }
        wallCollision(objArray[i]);
    }

    if (objArray.length > 0)
        wallCollision(objArray[objArray.length - 1])
}

function staticCollision(ob1, ob2, emergency = false)
{
    let overlap = ob1.radius + ob2.radius - distance(ob1, ob2);
    let smallerObject = ob1.radius < ob2.radius ? ob1 : ob2;
    let biggerObject = ob1.radius > ob2.radius ? ob1 : ob2;

    // When things go normally, this line does not execute.
    // "Emergency" is when staticCollision has run, but the collision
    // still hasn't been resolved. Which implies that one of the objects
    // is likely being jammed against a corner, so we must now move the OTHER one instead.
    // in other words: this line basically swaps the "little guy" role, because
    // the actual little guy can't be moved away due to being blocked by the wall.
    if (emergency) [smallerObject, biggerObject] = [biggerObject, smallerObject]
    
    let theta = Math.atan2((biggerObject.y - smallerObject.y), (biggerObject.x - smallerObject.x));
    smallerObject.x -= overlap * Math.cos(theta);
    smallerObject.y -= overlap * Math.sin(theta); 

    if (distance(ob1, ob2) < ob1.radius + ob2.radius) {
        // we don't want to be stuck in an infinite emergency.
        // so if we have already run one emergency round; just ignore the problem.
        if (!emergency) staticCollision(ob1, ob2, true)
    }
}

function moveObjects() {
    for (let i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
        let ob = objArray[i];
        ob.x += ob.dx * dt;
        ob.y += ob.dy * dt;
    }    
}

function drawObjects() {
    for (let obj in objArray) {
        objArray[obj].draw();
    }
}

function draw() {
    
    currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    dt = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000; // delta time in seconds
    
    // dirty and lazy solution
    // instead of scaling down every velocity vector
    // we decrease the speed of time
    dt *= 0.1;

    if (clearCanv) clearCanvas();
    canvasBackground();
    
    if (!paused) {
        moveObjects();
        ballCollision();
    }
    
    drawObjects();
    
    //logger();
    
    lastTime = currentTime;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

/*
for (i = 0; i<numStartingSmallBalls; i++) {
    objArray[objArray.length] = new Ball(randomX(), randomY(), 3);
}*/

let N = 500;
let m = 2.66e-26;
let T = 300;
let dV = 50;
let k = 1.38e-23;
let v = 50;
let balls = 0;
let angolox;

for(let i = 0; i < 29; i++) { //ogni 50 velocità, con dv = 50, fino a 1500m/s, 
    probArray[i] = Math.floor(4 * Math.PI * N * (((m) / (2 * Math.PI * k * T))**1.5) * (v**2) * Math.exp((-m) / (2 * k * T) * (v**2)) * dV);//num molecole tra v e v+50
    v += 50;
}
v = 50;
for(let i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    let n = 0;
    while(n < probArray[i] && balls < 100) {
        angolox = ((Math.random() * 360) * Math.PI) / 180; //converted in radians;
        vel = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) + v); 
        objArray[objArray.length] = new Ball(randomX(), randomY(), Math.cos(angolox) * vel, Math.sin(angolox) * vel, 3);
        n++;
        balls++;
    }
    v += 50;
    }

draw();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: khaki;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
  }

  #title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px;
  }

  #balls {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  #myCanvas {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }

  section.footer {
    color: black;
    font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: small;
  }
  #disclaimer {
    font-size: 74%;
    color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>2d collision</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gas.css">
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
  
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1225%" height="650%" style="border:1px solid black; margin-top: 10px;"></canvas>
    <script src="gas.js"></script>
  

    <p>
      <strong>[X]</strong> to toggle SIZE of future balls <br>
      <strong>[K]</strong> to toggle clearCanvas(); <br>
      <strong>[P]</strong>: pause/unpause || <strong>[R]</strong>: [RESET]
    </p>

    <p>
      <a href="https://github.com/miskimit/miskimit.github.io/tree/master/ballsballsballs">source code on github</a>
    </p>

    <div id="disclaimer" align="center" style="word-break: break-word; width: 350px; display:inline-block;">

      <p>
        Make sure to press a few buttons and play around.<br>Made with pure javascript.
      </p>

    </div>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```